# Contract launch & dead blocks post "Start trading" call

Tags: solidity, bsc

I'm trying to assess amount of blocks between a call (function) which opens trade (Start Trading), and first trades made, but cannot find it in the code. Is it possible that this function is random within some pre-set margins?
https://bscscan.com/address/0x0d781f5b380f176a01044eb202c0fc89744ad044#code

1 - contract is created

2 - liquidity is added

3 - "Start Trading" function activated (manual)

4 - Deadblocks (cannot trade)

5 - First trades

6 - ...

Any idea?

Comment: Can you indicate which functions are involved in each step? It is not very clear what to look for when you say "start trading".

Comment: Simply trying to find amount of dead blocks after trading is enabled, and actual trading start (actual buys). As I noticed its not instant as usually, trade cannot be made till specific block after trading start function is enabled.

Comment: The contract has several function it is not clear which functions are invoked in each step.